# Reset Vim Window switching shortcut in Python Mode

Tags: vim, nerdtree

`ctrl+ww` cycle though all windows

I want to switch this shorcut to `ctrl + we` in my `Vim`

Then how do I set up my `.vimrc`?

I have conflicting shortcut for `ctrl + ww` and when switching between windows in `NERDTree` I want to type `Ctrl + w e` instead of `ctrl + ww`

Please help me! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nnoremap <C-w><C-e> <C-w><C-w>
nnoremap <C-w>e <C-w>w
```

should be enough but whatever plugin overrides the default behavior of `<C-w><C-w>` is wrong.